# Error while trying to import an external jar into ballerina module

Tags: wso2, ballerina

I am trying to import an external jar into ballerina. In this case it is from nd4j-native-platform-1.0.0-beta5.jar downloaded from maven-central. I can't figure out what the problem is.

The config of my Ballerina.toml file is as follows:

> Ballerina.toml

```
[project]
org-name= "user_name"
version= "0.1.0"

[platform]
target = "java8"

    [[platform.libraries]]
    path = "/Users/username/Code/Workspace6/ballerina-hackathon/ml-connector/java_dependencies/deeplearning4j-modelimport-1.0.0-beta5.jar"
    modules = ["ml_service"]
```

The file (load_model.bal) in my module named "ml_service" to load:

> load_model.bal

```
import ballerinax/java;

function loadModel() returns handle = @java:Method {
    name: "ClassPathResource",
    class: "org.nd4j.linalg.io"
} external;

public function main() {
var load = loadModel();

}
```

The error I am getting when I try to build is as follows:

```
computername:ml-connector username$ ballerina build ml_service
Compiling source
    user_name/ml_service:0.1.0

Creating balos
    target/balo/ml_service-2019r3-java8-0.1.0.balo
error: user_name:ml_service:load_model.bal:9:1: {ballerinax/java}CLASS_NOT_FOUND message=org.nd4j.linalg.io
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what the problem was, the jar that I had did not have the class ClassPathResource in it. To add to this, the code should have been modified in the load_model.bal file. The function classPathResource had to be declared as a Constructor and not a Method as I had previous declared it to be. It also had to take a parameter of type string. I have attached the code I used below.

> load_model.bal

```
import ballerinax/java;
import ballerina/io as _;

function loadModel(handle path) returns handle = @java:Constructor {
    class: "org.nd4j.linalg.io.ClassPathResource"
} external;


public function main() {
    var load = loadModel(java:fromString("model_path"));
}
```